# Action<>,wait for a extra action to complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, 7zip

```
here it is:

        Action<int, ProgressBar, Label, Label, int, Button> downloadFileAsync = (i, pb, label2, label1, ServID, button1) =>
    {
        var bd = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var fn = bd + "/" + i + ".7z";
        var down = new WebClient();
        DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler dpc = (s, e) =>
        {
            label1.Text = "Download Update: " + i + " From: " + ServID;
            int rec =Convert.ToInt16(e.BytesReceived / 1024);
            int total =Convert.ToInt16(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024)  ;
            label2.Text = "Downloaded: " + rec.ToString() + " / " + total.ToString() + " KB";
            pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        };
        AsyncCompletedEventHandler dfc = null;  dfc = (s, e) =>
        {
            down.DownloadProgressChanged -= dpc;
            down.DownloadFileCompleted -= dfc;
            CompressionEngine.Current.Decoder.DecodeIntoDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/" + i + ".7z", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            File.Delete(fn);
               if (i == ServID)
                {

                   button1.Enabled = true;
                   label1.Text = "Game Is Up-To-Date.Have Fun!!";
                  label2.Text = "Done..";
               }
         down.Dispose();
        };
```

My only problem now is when the program is extracting the downloaded file

```
CompressionEngine.Current.Decoder.DecodeIntoDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/" + i + ".7z", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

In some files its take time to extract the downloaded file 
so how I can tell the program to wait until decompressing is complete?
(I use BackgroundWorker)

Comment: The background worker raises an event when the work is complete. Have you tried to attach an event handler to that event?

Comment: yea i did.
the problam is that the backgroungworker finish before the curret file download complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most elegant way to handle this type of processing is using TPL Dataflow.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx

That would require you to refactor existing code a bit.  However, it provides an outstanding mechanism to express parallel programming tasks that have a sense of order to them.  It is will worth taking the time to learn Dataflow if you write this type of code with any kind of frequency.

If that is not an option, have a look at the AutoResetEvent.  It will allow one task to wait, without consuming resources, until the task it depends on is finished.

> Notifies a waiting thread that an event has occurred

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx